# Evaluate the limit $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\sqrt{1-\sin(5x)}-\sqrt{1+\sin(5x)}}{x^2+x}$

Tags: calculus, limits, functions

Trying to find

> $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \dfrac{\sqrt{1-\sin(5x)}-\sqrt{1+\sin(5x)}}{x^2+x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \dfrac{(1-\sin(5x))-(1+\sin(5x))}{(x^2+x)(\sqrt{1-\sin(5x)}+\sqrt{1+\sin(5x)})}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \dfrac{-2\sin(5x)}{(x^2+x)(\sqrt{1-\sin(5x)}+\sqrt{1+\sin(5x)})}$$

How to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{(1-\sin{(5x)})-(1+\sin{(5x)})}{x(x+1)(\sqrt{1-\sin{(5x)}}+\sqrt{1+\sin{(5x)}})}=\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{-2\sin{(5x)}}{2x}=-5$$

Comment: Why $x^2$ disappeared in first $lim$?

Comment: because $x^2+x=x(x+1)$

Comment: I cannot get the same result. Can You give more detailed solution?

Comment: How can You transform $(x+1)$ multiplied by sum of radicals to $2$?

Comment: $\lim_{x\to 0}(x+1)=1$ and $\lim_{x\to 0}(\sqrt{1-\sin{(5x)}}+\sqrt{1+\sin{(5x)}})=2$....

Answer (score 0):

Recall
$$\sin^2(a) + \cos^2(a) = 1$$
Hence,
$$1 \pm \sin(2a) = ( \cos(a) \pm \sin(a))^2$$
For small $x$, we have
$$\sqrt{1 \pm \sin(5x)} = ( \cos(5x/2) \pm \sin(5x/2))$$
Use this along with the fact that $\lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{\sin(\alpha x)}{x} = \alpha$ to conclude the limit.